# How to flush data automatically of log file owned by syslog?

Tags: linux, systemd

I am running Go binary as a service, and created a log file owned by syslog to maintain all logs.

This is my service file::

```
[Unit]
Description=myapp

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=30
WorkingDirectory= /home/go/src/myapp
ExecStart=/home/go/src/myapp/myapp  

# myapp.log owned by syslog
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/log/myapp
ExecStartPre=/bin/chown syslog:adm /var/log/myapp
ExecStartPre=/bin/chmod 755 /var/log/myapp
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=myapp                           

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After this using rsyslog to manage syslogs, created a file inside /etc/rsyslog.d/myapp.conf with the following content:

```
if $programname == 'myapp' then /var/log/myapp/myapp.log
& stop
```

After this I restarted service.It creates a log file for me.
I have two questions regarding log file, as follows::

1. Now I have to flush all log file data after every 15 days. Is there
   any method to do this??
2. There are some api which will give response in every 3 minutes, so
   Is there any way to restrict some api from generating logs??

I am doing all this using systemd. Please suggest me if there method to create this type of log file attached with systemd service.

Comment: Your second question, which largely duplicates https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470181/ , is unanswerable.  Answerers are not telepathic, and so do not know the code of the program that contains "some API" and whether that program even allows detailed control of its log message generation.  This site also prefers one question per question, per the [help].  Since you have already asked that unanswerable question before, you are better off not asking it again in a multiple-question question here.

Answer (score 1):

1. To flush that log you can use standard logrotate, with reload of rsyslog in postrotate script. [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)
2. As you can see. Systemd will write all standard output into syslog, So filtering which api should or shouldn't go to stdout has to be done inside application.

Comment: where I can create logrotate message file? and how to attach logrotate with logfile

Comment: install logrotate and put logrotate file into `/etc/logrotate.d`. attaching to file is first line in logrotate file(the one before '{' sign). There are awesome examples in that man page

Comment: I have created a logrotate file with the name myapp, and added these lines inside file::
`/var/log/myapp/myapp.log 
{
 rotate 5
 daily
 size 100k
 compress
}`

after this I restart the service, for testing purpose I am using size 100k here, after exceeding 100k size it there is no zip file inside myapp folder, even it's size grows bigger and bigger

Comment: I am just restarting service after these changes, and according to these configurations, a new zip file of log will be created when it exceed the size of 100k. But It didn't work like this. Can you please tell me why this happening here??

Comment: Logrotate is running via cron. As daily job. Wait until tomorrow or run it manually `logrotate -f yourconfig -v`

Comment: Using rsyslog's built-in mechanism is a much better idea, if one is using rsyslog at all.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33548/  `logrotate` is not something that one should be using this century.